# black screen on run and install

Tags: asus

I got an Asus fz50vw-ns52 that I've been trying to install both Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.10 and with both running Ubuntu off the jump drive and trying to install it I just see a black screen (without backlight) after I make my choice and it reboots.

I read a review when I was researching the laptop that said the laptop had not been released in the us yet and I can't find it on the Asus site. I got it of newegg.

Comment: What did you use to burn the ISOs to the USBs?

Comment: I have seen computers that don't boot when there is a USB drive plugged in.  Try burning to a DVD and installing from dvd-rom rather.

Comment: Universal USB Installer @Zacharee1 I plugged it into an external monitor and got some new info. DRM:i915 firmware load error print [i915] **error** failed to load firmware i915/skl dmc ver1.bin

Comment: Try using [Rufus](HTTP://Rufus.akei.ie) to burn the USB instead

Comment: Sorry, it's rufus.akeo.ie

Answer (score 0):

I have the ASUS FZ50VW-NS51 and I was able to get ubuntu to load using

```
i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 nouveau.modeset=0 acpi_osi=! acpi_backlight=vendor idle=nomwait
```

as kernel parameters (Press e at the grub menu after selecting the boot option you want).

Edit: Any time you reboot before installing the latest nvidia drivers you will have to specify the same parameters in order to boot.

Comment: I was never able to get it working and last week the laptop died. I think it was the memory, a month or 2 ago it was the HDD that failed. I'll never buy an ASUS again, it's only 6 months old.